# vgaswitcheroo not working

Tags: 14.04, vgaswitcheroo

have ubuntu 14.04 desktop installed and I am trying to switch off my graphic card by typing

> sudo echo OFF /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch

but it didn't switch off and also my ethernet is not working. Help?